# Trying to switch between 4 stylesheets using a button and javascript

Tags: javascript, css, button

I have been looking around here, and found ways to toggle between 2 css files, but not more files than that. I need to use 1 button to alternate between 4 different files. My main css that is loaded with the html is called `style1.css`.

I found a js snippet that does this with images, and what it does is put all the images in an array, and take the first object out of and places it last in the array. I have been able to make this work:

```
var imageUrls = ["images/paulfr.jpg", "images/johnfr.jpg", 
"images/georgefr.jpg", "images/ringofr.jpg"];

    function changeImage(){
        var img = document.getElementById('image');
        var imageUrl = imageUrls.shift();
        img.src = imageUrl;
        imageUrls.push(imageUrl);
    }
```

Now, I tried remaking it for stylesheet files, but it fails:

```
var stylesUrls = ["css/style1.css", "css/style2.css", 
"css/style3.css", "css/style4.css"];

    function changeStylesheet(){
        var style = document.getElementById('styles');
        var stylesUrl = stylesUrls.shift();
        style.src = stylesUrl;
        stylesUrls.push(stylesUrl);
    }
```

I did make sure that stylesheet id is 'styles'. Could somebody please show me where I go wrong?

Comment: how you tried to debug this to see what happens to the stylesUrls when you click the button? This could work but the path of your css file could be wrong.

Comment: I guess I have not debugged enough. If you say should work, that gives me motivation to try some more =)

Comment: changing the array is working ok, I tested. It does take out the first element and pushing it to the end of the array but it's not assigning correctly the new stylesheet to you link tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change src to href:

```
style.src = stylesUrl;
```

to

```
style.href = stylesUrl;
```

**Full solution:**

```
var stylesUrls = ["css/style1.css", "css/style2.css", 
"css/style3.css", "css/style4.css"];

      window.onload = function(){
           var refButton = document.getElementById("change-styles");

            refButton.onclick = function() {
                      var style = document.getElementById('styles');
                      var stylesUrl = stylesUrls.shift();
                      style.href = stylesUrl;
                      stylesUrls.push(stylesUrl);
                  
            }
        };
```

**HTML**

```
<link href="css/style1.css" rel="stylesheet" id="styles" type="text/css">

<a href="#" id="change-styles">Change</a>
```